# Generating Text to a PNG File with Transparent Background

Tags: c#, png, transparency

I need to Export some PNG Images with Transparent Background from a C# Application .
But that is not a Huge Concern .
What make's it complicated and beyond my knowledge is ,how am i able to Export to PNG Image File With Transparent Background with Some Text in it,like a Label only without Background so in that way i can export as many images i want with Different Text into it.
And that PNG should had the Size of the Label ,or if there is a way it should FIT the Font Size and Text Length ,so it Height and Width should be same as Font one .

Bests.

Comment: What do you mean with Export? Do you already have those png somewhere or you want to create new png files from code?

Comment: No i dont have ,but i could Generate them ,it's the same Situation like Snapshoting or Printscreen my form ,so sory i mean how to Generate PNG's .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `Bitmap` and `Graphics` classes, along with the `Font` class and the `TextRenderer.MeasureText` method.

Comment: @David Heffernan, its right but there should be Graphics.MeasureString method instead of TextRenderer.MeasureText

Comment: @Waqas You can make that edit yourself. Even though you don't have the rep to commit the edit you can make it and I'm sure SLaks will approve it if you are correct.

Comment: @David Heffernan sure let me try

Comment: @David, @Raja: What? There's nothing wrong with TextRenderer, and it doesn't need a Graphics object.

Comment: TextRenderer is in System.Windows.WinForms namespace whereas Graphics is in System.Drawing, which is more feasible for non-windows application, however it TextRenderer will also work perfect if you have no such limitations.